# PHP GD: The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors

Tags: php, gd, captcha

I try to make Captcha via PHP GD. But unfortunately I encounter to a problem!
PHP tell me:

```
The image “http://127.0.0.1/par.php” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.
```

My code is this

```
<?php

  header ('Content-Type: image/png');
  $im = @imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20)
        or die('Cannot Initialize new GD image stream');
  $text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
  $red = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 0, 0); 
  for ($i=0;i<=120;$i=$i+1){
      for ($j=0;$j<=20;$j=$j+1){
          imagesetpixel($im, $i,$j,$red);
      }
  }
  imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  'A Simple Text String', $text_color);
  imagepng($im);
  imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$im = @imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20)
      or die('Cannot Initialize new GD image stream');
```

You first hide the real error and TRY to display something...

which you can't display because you don't look for it,

and expose the image no matter if it really got generated.

Then you go on stackoverflow and hope someone can guess the error you might have simply suppressed using `@` operator.

Make sure there is nothing before `<?php` and if you have, remove `?>` at the end.

To make sure you have GD installed try this in a new php file:

```
<?php
if (extension_loaded('gd') && function_exists('gd_info')) {
    echo "PHP GD library is installed on your web server";
}
else {
    echo "PHP GD library is NOT installed on your web server";
}
```

Comment: I delete @ from my code! But this time I just saw a white screen! I think problem is in first line! in: header ('Content-Type: image/png'); But I don't know what is the problem!

Comment: @SalehSalehizadeh I posted two things that maybe help

Comment: And It worked! really Thanks! very helpful tip! I wonder why I didn't checked it before :)

Comment: @SalehSalehizadeh yay! happy coding Saleh

Answer (score 3):

the problem is in those for

change it for:

```
for ($i=0; $i < 120 ; $i++) {  
    for ($j=0; $j < 20 ; $j++) { 

        imagesetpixel($im, $i,$j,$red);
    }
}
```

EDIT

this, is the code that i tested:

```
header ('Content-Type: image/png');
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20)
      or die('Cannot Initialize new GD image stream');
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 14, 91);
$red = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 0, 0); 

for ($i=0; $i < 120 ; $i++) {  
    for ($j=0; $j < 20 ; $j++) {  

        imagesetpixel ($im ,$i,$j ,$red);
    }

 }
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,'A Simple Text String', $text_color);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

result:

[image]

Comment: No! It's not the problem!

Comment: i tested your code, and work fine, the only change are those for

Comment: Thanks! But It didn't work for me! maybe problem is not in my code! Maybe My Apache server is the problem!

Answer (score 1):

This problem is occurring in FireFox only and not Chrome. You should go ahead if it´s not causing other problems. Shouldn't remove the header() even though error display disapears.

Comment: thanks for your answer but problem was in my apache server configuration.

Comment: @SalehSalehizadeh could you please tell us what was the problem on your _apache server configuration_ and **how** you solve it? 

It helps a lot.

Comment: Sorry that I answer you so late! 
I made a mistake in my reply! Problem was in GD library that I hadn't installed it before  I try this codes! 
look at DanFromGermany answer in top (answer which mark as true answer). if you GD library not installed in your apache sever. you should install it! just Google it!
if you use ubuntu this should solve your problem:
[link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-or-add-php-gd-support-to-apache/)

Answer (score -2):

Most probably your php outputs some warning or notices that mess up with your image data. 
Try to break your code before **imagepng()** function call to see if any errors or warnings are generated or try to stop all warnings and notices in your php.ini or with ini_set.

Comment: -1 for `Try to stop all warnings and notices in your php.ini or with ini_set` - the better advice would be: Fix the warnings notices and errors instead of suppressing them.